# Unable to store data via mysqli_connect

Tags: php, android, mysqli

Hey guys currently I'm trying to create a login activity for android application and I have no idea why the user data is not stored upon registration. Is there something wrong with the php files as shown below?

Register.php stores registration for users

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("mysql13.000webhost.com", "a1641537_fetch", "password", "a1641537_fetchdb");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO Fetch (name, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ");

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $name, $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

FetchUserData.php fetches username and password of a user.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("mysql13.000webhost.com", "a1641537_fetch", "password", "a1641537_fetchdb");

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM Fetch WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $name, $username, $password);

    $user = array();

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
        $user[name] = $name;
        $user[username] = $username;
        $user[password] = $password;
    }

    echo json_encode($user);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetch` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in mysql so you need to quote it in backticks.

For example:

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO `Fetch` (name, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ");
```

To catch these kinds of mistakes, it is useful to add error handling. I prefer to do that by having msyqli throw an exception when anything goes wrong.

To activate that, just add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script and make sure that errors are displayed.

If you don't add any try - catch blocks yourself, php will show you a detailed `unhandled exception error` when a problem occurs so you can take it from there. Obviously in live code this is not the preferred way to handle that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes the problem is due to that! :)